# Getting URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Because of an HTTP_REFERER issue I need to make a URL pass from an https site to http.

I have this bit of JavaScript but it is not working.

```js
<a href="http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/display" onclick="location.href='http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/display?https&url=' + escape(window.location.href)">Save this page as PDF</a>
```

Can I also find out how I would append the current site using JavaScript their API URL?

```
 http://api.htm2pdf.co.uk/urltopdf?apikey=yourapikey&url=http://www.example.com
```

Any advice?

Comment: Is there a reason that you have the anchor tag AND the javascript in there?

Comment: Hi Martin, this is what I was given. I am actually also trying to make the api link work - any advice on that would be appreciated

Comment: You want for somebody to click the link, and for the current page to be sent to the htm2pdf.co.uk API?

Answer (score 0):

Need to block the initial anchor tag event.

```
    <a href="http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/display" onclick="event.preventDefault();window.location.href='http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/display?https&url='+escape(window.location.href);">Save this page as PDF</a>
```

Comment: Thank you I will try that - as a follow up if I use their api link how would I add the right javascript so that it replaced http://example.com below with the actual page url? [link]http://api.htm2pdf.co.uk/urltopdf?apikey=yourapikey&url=http://www.example.com

Answer (score -1):

I would use either javascript or the href attribute, not both.  I don't see how they would work well together.

You can use .preventDefault() as noted, but why put the href attribute there in the first place?

Is this what you're looking for?  It should work on both http or https sites.

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://api.htm2pdf.co.uk/urltopdf?apikey=yourapikey&url=' + window.location.href, '_blank', 'location=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">Save as PDF</a>
```